# Getting table height return minus value

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="checkfeedhide">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <fieldset class="schedule-border">
            <div class="row">...</div>
            <div class="row check_list_feed">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the height of each table with class name `tbl-each`. So, I try to get those table as shown in below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkfeedhide").children().find('.tbl-each').each(function(index, val) {

        var height = $(this).height();
        console.log(height+' '+index);
    });
});
```

But when I get the height of table with above code, it always return `-2`. How do I get the actual value of each table with class name `.tbl-each`.

Comment: The code in your question does not replicate the behavior you describe. Please edit your question to include a [verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. It's wokring for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkfeedhide").children().find('.tbl-each').each(function(index, val) {
        var height = $(this).height();
        console.log(height+' '+index);
    });
});
```

```html
<html> 
<head>
    <title>User Registration PHP & MYSQL</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.table.table-bordered.tbl-each {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab-pane" id="checkfeedhide">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <fieldset class="schedule-border">
            <div class="row">...</div>
            <div class="row check_list_feed">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <P>FIRST TABLE</P>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th> 
                                <th>Age</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <P>SECOND TABLE</P>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th> 
                                <th>Age</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td> 
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <P>THIRD TABLE</P>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th> 
                                <th>Age</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td> 
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <P>FOURTH TABLE</P>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">
                            <tr>
                                <th>A</th>
                                <th>B</th> 
                                <th>C</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>10</td>
                                <td>20</td> 
                                <td>30</td> 
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <P>FIFTH TABLE</P>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th> 
                                <th>Age</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td> 
                                <td>94</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <P>SIXTH TABLE</P>
                        <table class="table table-bordered tbl-each">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th> 
                                <th>Age</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { $('.tbl-each').each(function(){ console.log($(this).height()); }) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table style="height: 20px;border: 1px solid gray;width: 20px;" class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table  style="height: 40px;border: 1px solid gray;width: 20px;" class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table style="height: 10px;border: 1px solid gray;width: 20px;" class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table style="height: 12px;border: 1px solid gray;width: 20px;" class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table style="height: 11px;border: 1px solid gray;width: 20px;" class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                        <table style="height: 22px;border: 1px solid gray;width: 20px;" class="table table-bordered tbl-each">...</table>
                    </div>
```